# Can a node have a 'wild card' ZIP Code that matches all ZIP codes?

Tags: 7, location

I am using [Drupal 7.43](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.43) and the [Location module 7.x-3.7.](https://www.drupal.org/project/location/releases/7.x-3.7) Can a node have a 'wild card' ZIP Code that matches all ZIP codes?

Application:
Have a filterable view return a list of nodes with ZIPs within a given radius of a given ZIP code *and* also return all resources with a "wild card" ZIP.

Setup:
We have two node types: Resources and Organizations. Most have an address with a ZIP code associated with them. Some are tagged as "state-wide" or "national;' these do not have an address.

We have a page that lists all Resources and Orgs tagged with (for example) "Emergency Funding." There's an exposed filter on this page that lets visitors enter their ZIP code and a radius to filter down the results on the page. We figured out the logic to make the page return all statewide/national resources and all those within the given radius. But we wondered, "Can a node have a 'wild card' ZIP Code that matches all ZIP codes?"